# App to find words that you can’t remember

Tags: web-apps, language, dictionary

There is an app called [Tip of My Tongue](http://chir.ag/projects/tip-of-my-tongue/) that allows you to search for words based on parts of the word that you remember and the meaning. However, the "meaning" search doesn’t actually utilise synonyms - it merely searches the text of the dictionary definition of a word. I want an app that actually searches for synonyms.

Vital features:

- Limit words by letters at the start, end or somewhere in the word
- Limit results to a synonym of a particular word
- Web app

To clarify: Suppose you know that there is a synonym of "fast" and all you remember is that it ends with "y". The app should be able to find it for you.

Comment: Why don't you use the English Language SE?

Comment: @DeerHunter: Single word requests are contentious as it is. When you are searching for a particular word only that makes the question much less useful to other people and hence too localised

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[One look](http://www.onelook.com/?clue=fast&loc=revfp3&w=*y) is a reverse dictionary, but it provides exactly this functionality.

Features:

- Web app
- Filter by words related to a particular word
- Filter by part of speech